# error installing glove-python-> link.exe failed with exit status 1181

Tags: windows-10, python-3.5, build-tools

I am trying to install glove-python package for python 3.5 x64 but I got an error as shown below. (Note : I have Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools installed on windows 10)

Note : I searched and found that this error may be due to spaces that exist in the directory name for some files https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815645/you-receive-a-fatal-error-lnk1181-error-message-when-you-build-a-manag , and that I have to put the name of folder containing spaces between quotation marks.
But how to change the path for example for LIPBATH variable to put quotes? How can I access these variables containing the paths that cause problems?

```
C:\Users\ESCA>pip3 install glove-python
Collecting glove-python
Using cached glove_python-0.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from glove-python)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from glove-python)
Building wheels for collected packages: glove-python
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for glove-python ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dpaf49i6\\glove-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5fnavjwipip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
 running bdist_wheel
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove
 copying glove\corpus.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove
 copying glove\glove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove
 copying glove\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove
 running build_ext
 building 'glove.glove_cython' extension
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-I                                                                                 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcglove/glove_cython.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/glove_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
 glove_cython.c
 glove/glove_cython.c(1692): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/glove_cython.c(1701): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/glove_cython.c(2348): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/glove_cython.c(2357): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_glove_cython build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/glove_cython.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove\glove_cython.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove\glove_cython.cp35-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp
 LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/fopenmp'; ignored
 glove_cython.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_glove_cython' specified multiple times; using first specification
 Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove\glove_cython.cp35-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove\glove_cython.cp35-win_amd64.exp
 Generating code
 Finished generating code
 building 'glove.metrics.accuracy_cython' extension
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove\metrics
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcglove/metrics/accuracy_cython.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
 accuracy_cython.c
 glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.c(1569): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.c(1578): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.c(1587): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 creating C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dpaf49i6\glove-python\build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove\metrics
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_accuracy_cython build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove\metrics\accuracy_cython.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/metrics\accuracy_cython.cp35-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp
  LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/fopenmp'; ignored
  accuracy_cython.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_accuracy_cython'   specified multiple times; using first specification
  Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/metrics\accuracy_cython.cp35-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/metrics\accuracy_cython.cp35-win_amd64.exp
 Generating code
 Finished generating code
 building 'glove.corpus_cython' extension
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /EHsc /Tpglove/corpus_cython.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/corpus_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
 corpus_cython.cpp
 glove/corpus_cython.cpp(1796): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2025): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2235): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2310): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3251): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3403): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
 glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3431): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
 glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3457): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" stdc++.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_corpus_cython build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/corpus_cython.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove\corpus_cython.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove\corpus_cython.cp35-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
 LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/fopenmp'; ignored
 LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/ffast-math'; ignored
 LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/march=native'; ignored
 LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'stdc++.lib'
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for glove-python
 Running setup.py clean for glove-python
 Complete output from command c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dpaf49i6\\glove-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
 usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: -c --help-commands
 or: -c cmd --help

 error: option --all not recognized

 ----------------------------------------
Failed cleaning build dir for glove-python
Failed to build glove-python
Installing collected packages: glove-python
Running setup.py install for glove-python ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dpaf49i6\\glove-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mkye10h8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'glove.corpus_cython' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /EHsc /Tpglove/corpus_cython.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/corpus_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
corpus_cython.cpp
glove/corpus_cython.cpp(1796): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2025): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2235): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2310): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3251): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3403): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3431): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3457): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" stdc++.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_corpus_cython build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/corpus_cython.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove\corpus_cython.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove\corpus_cython.cp35-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/fopenmp'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/ffast-math'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/march=native'; ignored
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'stdc++.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dpaf49i6\\glove-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mkye10h8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dpaf49i6\glove-python\
```

Answer (score 5):

I got same error. This solution may help you try it.

pip install glove==1.0.0

Comment: On Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 and using Python 3.7, I find that this answer is still best. I could not get glove_python to work or find any good help to make it work. This answer also helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/60396650/996205